# Setting UILabel to hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uilabel

I have this code that sets a few labels, and hides and few others and then removes a Custom Loading view I made from the screen, here is the code:

```
self.yourPlanLabel.text = [infoArray objectAtIndex:0];
self.yourMealLabel.text = [infoArray objectAtIndex:1];
self.yourBalanceLabel.text = [infoArray objectAtIndex:2];
self.usernameField.hidden = YES;
self.passwordField.hidden = YES;
self.loginBtn.hidden = YES;
self.yourPlanLabel.hidden = NO;
self.yourMealLabel.hidden = NO;
self.yourBalanceLabel.hidden = NO;
//remove loading view
[self.loadingView removeFromSuperview];
```

But the loading view dissapears first, and then a couple second later the labels appear/ disappear depending what I set it to, why is the loading view disappearing first, when it is at the bottom of the code?

Thanks for the help :)

Here is my how I call the loading view:

```
self.loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.loadingView];
[self.loadingView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2 +32)];
```

And here is the .m of the loading view

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0a34fb49375dfeaca39

I am now doing this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.yourPlanLabel.text = [infoArray objectAtIndex:0];
    self.yourMealLabel.text = [infoArray objectAtIndex:1];
    self.yourBalanceLabel.text = [infoArray objectAtIndex:2];

    self.usernameField.hidden = YES;
    self.passwordField.hidden = YES;
    self.loginBtn.hidden = YES;

    self.mealLabel.hidden = NO;
    self.planLabel.hidden = NO;
    self.balanceLabel.hidden = NO;
    self.yourPlanLabel.hidden = NO;
    self.yourMealLabel.hidden = NO;
    self.yourBalanceLabel.hidden = NO;
    self.loadingView.hidden = YES;
    [self.loadingView removeFromSuperview];
});
```

And still not working?

Comment: Whhat is a "Custom Loading view"? How is it called?

Comment: @Zaph can you see edit

Comment: @timblue Is there any chance you might be doing any of this on a thread other than the main thread?

Comment: @JustSid See my edit I tried putting everything on main queue and still didnt work?

Comment: Try calling `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview of the labels before the call to `removeFromSuperview`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing all the above settings in viewDidLoad, try moving the hiding function in 
viewDidAppear.

so its

```
-(void)viewDidAppear
{
        [self.loadingView removeFromSuperview];
}
```